# Docker Compose port issue. Cannot launch docker project on localhost

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I am on a mac (El Capitan, stable, `10.11.6`) with **Docker Desktop for Mac** stable installed.

I am running a simple javascript app on the official node image. Here's what the `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/local/src
```

And here's the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    container_name: myproject_dev
    build: .
    command: npm run development
    ports:
     - "1234:8000"
     - "1235:8080"
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./my-project:/usr/local/src
```

Running `docker-compose up` starts everything normally:

```
myproject_dev | http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
myproject_dev | webpack result is served from /assets/
myproject_dev | content is served from /usr/local/src
```

And `docker ps` shows that the ports are mapped:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                NAMES
820694f618b4        myproject_web   "npm run development"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1234->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1235->8080/tcp   myproject_dev
```

But I am unable to see the project page on the browser (using `localhost:1234`). Works fine when I run the project outside the docker. So, an issue with the project is ruled out.

Tried the following:

1. use a different `node` docker
2. switch between docker beta and stable versions
3. stop all host apache/nginx services

But no luck :( What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The service you're running is only listening to the container`localhost` interface, so nothing outside the container can access it. It needs to listen on `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: So, I changed to compose file by adding:

ports:
     - "0.0.0.0:41000:8000"
     - "0.0.0.0:41001:8080"

Is that what you mean? Still the same issue though

Comment: Nope, the issue is with the application configuration not the Compose file. The application needs to listen on the default public interface (`0.0.0.0`) not `localhost`.

Comment: You're right! Seems like that was the issue. Will check the application further and then mark your answer as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ping doesn't work that way; it queries a host, not a port of that host.  To test your ability to connect to a given port on a given host, you probably want something like `nc -vz <host> <port>`.

Comment: Ok. I meant that I can't see the project index.html on the browser. I just get a message that the "localhost didn't send any data"

Comment: And your command gives me this:
nc -vz localhost 1234                                                                                                                                                                             1 ↵ 

found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
 outif lo0
 src ::1 port 60274
 dst ::1 port 1234
 rank info not available
 TCP aux info available

Connection to localhost port 1234 [tcp/search-agent] succeeded!